# List all customers with Magento collection resource iterator

Tags: customer, collection

I use resource iterator to loading large collections:

```
$customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                   ->getCollection()
                   ->AddAttributeToSelect(array('email','taxvat','gender',
                                         'createad_at'),'inner');

Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk($customers->getSelect(),array('productcall'));
```

Then its show:

```
example@aa.es,000000T,2,1992-01-11 00:00:00
```

How can I list all customers instead of only one?

Comment: This is not reproducible, please add the code of `productcall` to the question.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but you have a typo in `createad_at`, which should result in a fatal error if there is no attribute with that name.